# Dependent Select Ajax jQuery Parser error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm experiencing trouble with 2 level dependent dropdown.

**When I select 1st dropdown, i have a PARSERERROR alert and second dropdown is not pouplated**

Please, any advice about what's wrong?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>CLASSIFICATION<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>                                         
    <select name="document_classification" id="document_classification" class="select-search"  data-placeholder="">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM rm_document_classification_id"; 
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "<option></option>";
                        echo "<option value='".$row['classification_id']."'>".$row['classification_description']."</option>";
                    }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>SUBJECTS<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select name="document_subject" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
     </select>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$( "select[name='document_classification']" ).change(function () {
var class_id = $(this).val();
//alert(class_id);

if(class_id) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'classification_id':class_id},
        success: function(data) {
            $('select[name="document_subject"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('select[name="document_subject"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (request,status, error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(status);
    }
    });

}else{
    $('select[name="document_subject"]').empty();
}
});
```

PHP

```
<?
   include_once "../config.php";

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM rm_document_subject_id
         WHERE subject_classification_id LIKE '%".$_GET['classification_id']."%'"; 

   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

   $json = [];
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json[$row['subject_id']] = $row['subject_description'];
   }

   echo json_encode($json);
 ?>
```

Thanks all. HID
Thanks all. HID
Thanks all. HID

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: @nogad When I select 1st, i have a PARSERERROR alert and second dropdown is not pouplated.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson PARSERERROR

Comment: Check the console. It should be more than just "parseerror"

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what is actually sent. Sounds like something else is being echo's besides the json or perhaps some error display is being output

Comment: How many times do you guys need OP to repeat *"parseerror"*. If you don't understand that look it up in $.ajax docs

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Never use short tags `<?` except from `<?=` (echo) since short tags have been disabled as default since a few versions back.

Comment: im seeing if we can set a new record. <blink>PARSERERROR</blink>

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at ub (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: @HidDencum it means something other than valid json is sent. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools and look at exactly what is sent

Comment: Try changing the first line `<?` to `<?php` in your PHP-file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, remove in your php file:

$json = [];

Comment: Why would the OP want to do that? No explanation about why at all. Even if the OP accepted this answer, it's a very poor answer.